# Consolidating a specific sheet from different workbooks into one master workbook in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

Every Month a unknown number of files in a desktop folder are edited.

I developed a 2 step macro to take this edited data and consolidate it into a master file. Firstly, I concatenate and transpose the data within each file prior to merging them all into a master data file. I loop through the folder, opening each file and create a new summary sheet in each. Secondly, I have a macro that loops through each file in the specified folder, selects the row of data, copies it, and then pastes it into a separate workbook entitled "MasterData".

My issue is that my second macro (the merge function), does not point to my destination file "master data" or the specific sheet within "master data" that I want the data to merge onto. I have included it below without the loop code,

```
Dim Line1 As String
Dim Line2 As String
Dim MasterData As Workbook
Dim MasterDataSheet As Worksheet
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
Line1 = Range("A2:HA2")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Line2 = Range("A3:HA3")
Set MasterData = Workbooks.Application.ActiveWorkbook
Worksheets("MasterData").Select
Worksheets("MasterData").Range("A1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("MasterData").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("MasterData").Range("A1")
 .Offset(RowCount, 0) = Line1
 .Offset(RowCount, 0) = Line2
End With
MasterData.Save
```

What should I do to make sure the data reaches the master data workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`,... instead of `Worksheets("name")`?

Look at left of your screen, where all Sheets are in dropdown and try using name that is before the name in brackets.

In picture both are named Sheet1 (Sheet1). use the first name without brackets, as:
`Sheet1.Range("A1")` instead of `Worksheets("MasterData").Range("A1")`

image:
[image of excel VB](http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/images/excel_macro_home2.png)

Comment: Hi thanks, ya I have tried using sheet instead of the sheet name, it didn't make a difference to the actual functionality, as in it still doesn't match the row. I just ended up calling the source sheet "Sheet1" and the destination sheet "MasterDataSheet" in my "masterData" workbook